# Hair particles on flat surface causing bald spots in radial shape

Tags: particles, hair

I am trying a create a flat rug however there is always this radial shape with bald spots, and always in the same location no matter what seed I tried. I have tried to play with the roughness, hair thickness, number of particles, children etc. but still can't find the answer.

Here is the file for reference:
[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WajcvJ_FeXnVZFx8w_2sBvdR6f85eu9D/view?usp=sharing)

[image: hair particles with bald spots]

Comment: It's not a bald spot, it's due to the fact that you are looking at the rug top down, making the hair particles that are directly underneath parallel to your view hence making the surface of the rug more visible in that spot. I've checked you file and the particles are pefectly even. https://imgbox.com/RVw83llz

Comment: You can avoid to have this effect by just adding some variations to your hair particles, adding a little brownian force for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well As I said in the comments, there is no "bald spot" at all in you rug, it's just the way you set up your camera and your particles and (I didn't mention this in the comments) your lighting that makes it look that way.

In your original file, I just removed the lamp, used an HDRi instead and it looks better :

[image: No lamp]

You can still see a spot in the middle and it's caused by the reasons I mentioned earlier. But see how it looks when I just move the camera a bit to the side :

[image: different angle]

For the particles settings part, unless you want your rug to have spiky, perfectly vertical hair, you would want to add more variations to your hair particles. That would not only avoid problems like this but it would make your rug more reallistic too.

The easiest way I know is to add a bit of `Brownian` to the particles physics in the `Physics` section (this setting is very sensitive so don't overdo it, a value of `0.001` is enough):

[image: Physics section]

Note that the `Physics` section only appear when you check the `Advanced` check box on the very top of the particle settings :

[image]

To see the Brownian's effect though, make sure your particles have enough segments and the rendered path have enough steps:

[image: Segments]
[image: Steps]

[image: Rug with brownian]

In this last render, I used your original camera angle and lighting, but I reduced the number of child particles to `30` because your value of `400` is too much (something like `100` would be more than enough for a final render in my opinion).

I hope my answer helped you in some way.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! The brownian setting helped a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome.